# SharePoint 2013 REST API, filter list items by datetime

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I need to get the item from a list that was created today.

Basically an item is created once a day in a list at any time. What I need is to be able to get that item using rest api.

```
http://server.domain.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items/?$filter=Created eq datetime('DD.MM.YYYY')
```

But this doesn't work ...

Any idea how I can get the today created item using rest?

Answer (score -1):

The datetime function should be used like `datetime'01.03.2013'`

```
http://server.domain.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items/?$filter=Created eq datetime'01.03.2013'
```